# kmod-staging-3.14* on Fedora 19?

Tags: kernel-modules, fedora

I use Fedora 19 (Schrödinger’s Cat) on most computers as I prefer it over others (I probably would use Fedora 20 *if* I could have Gnome 3.8 plus a few other packages).

My problem is that I use `kmod-staging` package for drivers (e.g. [SD card reader driver](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/102348/52956)), provided by the [RPMFusion repos](http://rpmfusion.org/). Now, when the system updates the kernel, the `kmod-staging` package (and `kmod-VirtualBox` package<sup>[Note1]</sup> need to be updated as well. So it updates, and when I reboot and it switches to the latest kernel, it throws errors as it can't load the drivers as they aren't there.

I would need `kmod-staging-3.14.8-100.fc19.x86_64` for it to match the kernel version - but it seems to have stop receiving updates, since the latest build available seems to be [`kmod-staging-3.13.9-100.fc19.x86_64`](http://download1.rpmfusion.org/free/fedora/updates/19/x86_64/repoview/kmod-staging-3.13.9-100.fc19.x86_64.html).

So my questions are:

1. Why is `kmod-staging` not updated on Fedora 19 anymore? It receives updates on Fedora 20 - Fedora 19 is still supported<sup>[Note2]</sup> and receives updates to other packages from the same repo like `kmod-VirtualBox`.
2. Is there any way I could get `kmod-staging` for the 3.14 kernel on Fedora 19 *(other than installing the Fedora 20 kernel + kmod-staging)*

<sup>If anything I would like the first question answered - don't mind too much about the second as I'll just roll back to the 13.9 kernel</sup>

[Note1] - Which doesn't have this problem and is still being updated - it even is shown in the [latest build list](http://download1.rpmfusion.org/free/fedora/updates/19/x86_64/repoview/index.html) ([here](http://download1.rpmfusion.org/free/fedora/updates/19/x86_64/repoview/kmod-VirtualBox-3.14.8-100.fc19.x86_64.html))

[Note2] - According to the [release schedule](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Fedora_Release_Life_Cycle), it should be supported a month after the release of the current version +2 ([not before 2014-10-14](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Releases/21/Schedule)), so it still has a while yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The RPMFusion project is run by volunteers and this is likely just lagging due to either no time to do it, or perceived low interest. From the FAQ:

*excerpt [#1 from FAQ](http://rpmfusion.org/FAQ#What_is_RPM_Fusion.3F)*

> #### Q: What is RPM Fusion?
>
> RPM Fusion is a repository of add-on packages for Fedora and EL+EPEL maintained by a group of volunteers. RPM Fusion is not a standalone repository, but an extension of Fedora. RPM Fusion distributes packages that have been deemed unacceptable to Fedora.

*excerpt [#2 from FAQ](http://rpmfusion.org/FAQ#I_would_like_to_see_an_RPM_for_package_X._What_should_I_do.3F)*

> #### Q: I would like to see an RPM for package X. What should I do?
>
> A: Place a request in the wiki and hopefully a maintainer will decide to pick it up. If however you wish to see an additional feature added to an existing package, please file a bug against it in Bugzilla.

If I truly wanted this package I'd download the source RPM (SRPM) of the one you mentioned above and then modify it so that it included the newer version and rebuild it myself using `rpmbuild --rebuild`. It typically quite trivial to do this and will give you what you want.

If this seems to complicated you could open a ticket up in the wiki as described in the FAQ, but there are no guarantees when, if ever, anyone would get around to doing the rebuilding of this package.

Comment: compiling from the src rpm is not the issue - its whether it installs that usually the issue I find... [The Wishlist page](http://rpmfusion.org/Wishlist) has 'For update requests or package enhancements use bugzilla please.' report - I'll add a bug report soon.

Comment: @Wilf - I've found that it lags just as you've described myself. Hence the rebuilding approach.

Comment: i should be able to compile a version later - i still can't file a bug as I need to get the confirmation email to make *another* bugzilla  acc (already have a few for gnome, redhat, etc) to file the bug

Comment: I eventually got around to both recompiling and doing a bug report - I used the 14.2 SRPM  (example [here](http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3/stat/26/dist/92/size/6023733/name/staging-kmod-3.14.2-1.fc20.7.src.rpm)) as that was what the kmod-staging.14.8 for fc20 was made from - this resulted in [this RPM](https://www.dropbox.com/s/1q9brsbnfm8ue9r/kmod-staging-3.14.8-100.fc19.x86_64-3.14.2-1.fc19.7.x86_64.rpm). I also managed to make [this bug report](https://bugzilla.rpmfusion.org/show_bug.cgi?id=3286) after the account creation thing finally sent me the conformation email. Thanks :-)